# Are these Typescript 5.0.2 `const` type parameter issues expected?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am super pumped for the release of Typescript 5.0 to help mitigate issues around callers forgetting to add `as const` to some pretty gnarly function parameter types I've worked on, but there appears to either be bugs, or the feature is not as powerful I was hoping it'd be. Are the following expected limitations of the feature or bugs?

1. Object "validator" types ([issue already created](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53307))

```
type NotEmpty<T extends Record<string, any>> = keyof T extends never ? never : T;
const thing = <const O extends Record<string, any>>(o: NotEmpty<O>) => {
  return o;
};
const t = thing({foo: ''});
// is inferred as { foo: string } ❌

// BUT, when adding a mapped type to NotEmpty it works
type NotEmptyMapped<T extends Record<string, any>> = keyof T extends never ? never : {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] // ⬅️
};
const thingMapped = <const O extends Record<string, any>>(o: NotEmptyMapped<O>) => {
  return o;
};
const tMapped = thingMapped({foo: ''});
// is inferred as { foo: "" } ✅
```

2. Conditionally require or disallow an object key ([issue created after posting](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53320)):

```
type StringWithSpace = `${string} ${string}`;
type FooBar<Foo extends string, Bar extends Record<string, string>> = {
  foo: Foo;
} & (
  Foo extends StringWithSpace
  ? { bar: Bar }
  : { bar?: never }
);
//                                                            ⬇️ use const like inference
declare function requireBarIfFooHasSpace<Foo extends string, const Bar extends Record<string, string>>(foobar: FooBar<Foo, Bar>): Bar;
const foobar = requireBarIfFooHasSpace({
  foo: 'has space',
  bar: {
    hello: 'world'
  }
});
type inferredFooBar = typeof foobar;
//    ^? type inferredFooBar = {␊hello: string;␊} ❌
```

Potentially this a bug because const-like inference works correctly ✅ if `FooBar` is:

- simply

  ```
  type FooBar<Foo extends string, Bar extends Record<string, string>> = {
    foo: Foo;
    bar?: Bar;
  };
  ```
- or the `Foo extends` check is changed to simply

  ```
  Foo extends string
  ```

If these are expected, I unfortunately couldn't find any resources explaining these limitations. If one exists, my apologies.

**EDIT 1:** It appears these are indeed bugs, see linked issues.

**EDIT 2:** The second one is actually working as intended. That's a bit of a bummer, but makes sense why it's the case. See the linked issue for an explanation.

**EDIT 3:** A workaround (I think) for issue 2 is to add a "dummy" const type parameter, which presumably permits TS to use const-like inference for both versions of the intersected `bar` property.

```
type StringWithSpace = `${string} ${string}`;
type FooBar<Foo extends string, Bar extends Record<string, string>, DummyBar extends undefined> = {
  foo: Foo;
} & (
  Foo extends StringWithSpace
  ? { bar: Bar }
  : { bar?: DummyBar }
);
declare function requireBarIfFooHasSpace<
  Foo extends string, 
  const Bar extends Record<string, string>,
  const DummyBar extends undefined ⬅️
>(foobar: FooBar<Foo, Bar, DummyBar>): Bar;
const foobar = requireBarIfFooHasSpace({
  foo: 'has space',
  bar: {
    hello: 'world'
  }
});
type inferredFooBar = typeof foobar;
//    ^? type inferredFooBar = {␊readonly hello: "world";␊}
```

Comment: Tested with typescript v5.2 and these issues seem to have been resolved